# Open Source Resource Monitoring tools

Tags: windows-7, linux, open-source, resources, resource-monitor

Are there any open source resource monitoring tools similar to Window's Resource Monitor?

For Linux.

Comment: You should tell us for which operating system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer a really old question I asked along time ago.... One of the best tools I found is `sysstat` (or `sar`). There are other ones though such as `nagios`, `cacti`, `collectl`, and `atop`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but provided you want the same information offered by the Windows' Resource Monitor, but on Linux, then consider the 'top' and 'atop' applications. There's also 'free -m' to look at the available, used and cached RAM; 'iostat' ('iostat 2 10' - ten runs every two seconds) for disk IO, etc.

If you want a graphical tool, then we need to know more about the Linux side of things, such as the distribution you're using and the window manager, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For big fat solution, you could check http://www.cacti.net/. Beside tools mentioned by Michael, there are also `htop`, `lsof`, `bwm-ng`… generally – a lot of tools :)